# Tooltip на объектах QListView с фиксированныи положением Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

Нужно, чтобы tooltip имел фиксированное положение относительно объекта QListView. Внутри простая модель, строку передает без фокусов(почти), tooltip через роль Qt::ToolTipRole из модели. Динамически вычислять нужное положения для tooltip'а мне видится вполне реальным, можно кеширивать даже,основная проблема в следующем: Чтобы переопределять позицию окошка подсказки, планировалось унаследоваться от QListView, и там переопределить метод `bool event(QEvent *pe) override`

Прим.

```
class MyView : public QListView {
public:
  MyView(QWidget *parent) : QListView(parent) {}
  bool event(QEvent *pe) override {
    if (pe->type() == QEvent::ToolTip)
      //CODE!
    return QListView::event(pe);
  }
};
```

Но такая логика не взлетела, события tooltip вызываются при наведении мышкой на пустые области списка, но не на элементы. Как переопределить для элементов списка?

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено опытным путем, переопределяя helpEvent в делегате:

```
bool StartScreenHistiryListDelegate::helpEvent(
    QHelpEvent *event, QAbstractItemView *view,
    const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) {
  if (event->type() == QEvent::ToolTip) {
//Динамичесское вычесление позиции ToolTip
    QPoint globalToolTipPositionWithOffset( 
        view->mapToGlobal({0, 0}).x() +
            option.fontMetrics
                .size(Qt::TextSingleLine,
                      index.data().toString())
                .width() +
            20,
        view->mapToGlobal({0, 0}).y() - 15 +
            (sizeHint(option, index).height() * index.row()));
    QHelpEvent modernEvent(QEvent::ToolTip, event->pos(),
                           globalToolTipPositionWithOffset);
    QStyledItemDelegate::helpEvent(&modernEvent, view, option, index);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Здесь перехватывается событие `QEvent::ToolTip`, и создается новое, с новой позицией.

Этот код показывает ToolTip за последней буквой строки QListView